# Check size of uploaded data every second in a specific time from client-by PHP or Other server-side lang or scripting

Tags: php, validation, upload, size, server-side-scripting

I have a page with php code to upload user's picture for every account.Size of their image file must less than 100 kb size.

I want prevent uploading file more than 100 KB on server from users(in registering new user in image profile field) and **during uploading**(Not after uploading the entire file and just during uploading it), if the upload volume exceeds 100 KB, stop uploading progress and display warning for user by PHP(**Preferred**) OR any other script language **for server-side code**.

I searched by stackoverflow and google I didn't find any help or source about that.

Is any way to check size of uploaded data(not just size of a specific file) every second in a specific time from a client user by PHP OR Other server-side language (or server-side script)?

Comment: The PHP script isn't started until the file is fully uploaded. So it's not possible for it to check progress.

Comment: You can do a scandir() and then loop over the array of files, then for every file you check with filesize() adding to a total number. Now you can not do this at a specific time interval, but as soon as someone comes online you can trigger the operation with a php script.